# Remove Blanks in Excel using Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below example where I have 3 columns in "CONDITION"

If I have data in all the 3 columns then the results should be column2 and column3 as shown in fig.

[image]

I used the below formula for "Results with my formula"

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A2));NOT(ISBLANK( $B2));NOT(ISBLANK( $C2)));CONCATENATE( $B2; $C2)
```

But, I need the results as in "Expected Results" column

In case if the value in the above row is empty then the current value has to be posted in this cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: My local settings use `,` instead of `;` for the formula criteria delimiter.  You may need to switch out the `,` for `;`

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER(B3:B14&" "&C3:C14,LEN(A3:A14)*LEN(B3:B14)*LEN(C3:C14)>0)
```

[image]

---

If not then use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$3:$B$14)/(LEN($A$3:$A$14)*LEN($B$3:$B$14)*LEN($C$3:$C$14)>0),ROW($ZZ1)))&" "&INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$3:$B$14)/(LEN($A$3:$A$14)*LEN($B$3:$B$14)*LEN($C$3:$C$14)>0),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

put in first cell and copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you start on row 2, this macro should do the trick.

```
Sub Test()

Dim a as Long
Dim b as Long
Dim lastrow as Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

b = 2
For a = 2 To lastrow

If Cells(a, 1) <> "" Then

Cells(b, 7) = Cells(a, 2) & " " & Cells(a, 3)

b = b + 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Warcupine.  I have made the adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Another formula solution.

Formula in E2, copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13&" "&$C$2:$C$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$1)/($A$2:$A$13<>""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Note : please change from "," to ";" in suit with your own country regional settings.

[image]